# Why do I have the horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: css, sass

I am unable to figure out which section of the https://www.ebury.com/e-blog/ is causing horizontal scrollbar?

Can anyone please assist me in getting rid of it?

Comment: there is some structural problem.. If you use container-fluid in wplheader this problem will not exist. If you are not able to  modify the html then use .wplheader{ margin:0 15px;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a horizontal scroll bar because you have this code in your css.

```
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

I see no reason for the margin to exists. You could substitue the margin for padding if you need spacing.

**You should also note:**

Margins are not included in a size calculation for:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Cool thanks for assistance. The culprit was the `.row` class which was causing negative margins. Removing the `.row` div also removed the horizontal scrollbars. I could also have renamed the .row class to something else but I thought removing the div itself is better since it was not doing affecting much

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `class="row"` from the `<div>` tag below `<div class="wplheader">`. It should work perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "wplheader", place "row" inside the "container"

Answer (score 0):

in you class

```
 .wplheader{
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

and your done

Answer (score -1):

In .wplheader class use container-fluid before row

Answer (score -1):

You can try it

```
 .wplheader .row {margin: 0;}
 .wplheader .header {width: inherit;}
```